# Could not convert string containing special minus sign to float

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to convert a string of numbers to list of numbers. But I don't know what's wrong with it.

```
list(map(float,'''2.0, 1.1, 4.4, -3.1, −1.3, 3.9, 3.2 , −1.6 , 3.5
                  1.2, 2.5, 2.3, 1.9, 1.8, 2.9, −0.3, −2.4'''
    .replace('\n',',').split(',')))
```

It comes up with this error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' −1.3'

Comment: You need to `.strip()` each number.

Comment: It's got a space and a weird unicode dash in it.

Comment: The space should not be any problem, but those weird dashes aren't minus signs, you need to fix them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string contains the Unicode character `MINUS SIGN`, not a normal hyphen `-` (Unicode name `HYPHEN-MINUS`) which is used by Python as a minus sign.

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> s = '−1.3'
>>> float(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '−1.3'
>>> unicodedata.name(s[0])
'MINUS SIGN'
>>> t = '-1.3'
>>> float(t)
-1.3
>>> unicodedata.name(t[0])
'HYPHEN-MINUS'
```

You can replace them:

```
list(map(float, '''2.0, 1.1, 4.4, -3.1, −1.3, 3.9, 3.2 , −1.6 , 3.5
                   1.2, 2.5, 2.3, 1.9, 1.8, 2.9, −0.3, −2.4'''
    .replace('\n', ',').replace('−', '-').split(',')))
```